# How to set head and tail position in nodes graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I can not control an edge's head and tail position between 2 nodes.

I'm setting up a node like a graph below

[image: questionGraph]

```
digraph G{
  node [shape = "box"]
  a -> b
  b -> a
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first part is  basically the same answer that @marapet has given already:

```
digraph G
{
   node[ shape = "box" ];
   a:w -> b:w;
   a:e -> b:e[ dir = back ];
}
```

It produces a graph with round edges:

[image]

If that's OK, then marapet's answer should be accepted.

If you insist on the shape that you provided in your post, a bit more complicated procedure needs to be applied:

```
digraph G
{
    // we create the two nodes to be displayed
    node[ shape = "box" ];
    a b;
    //we also create four empty nodes for routing the edges
    node[ shape = point, height = 0 ];
    x1 x2 x3 x4;
    // we make sure that the nodes are arranged on the right levels
    { rank = same; x1 a x2 }
    { rank = same; x3 b x4 }

    // we draw the edges one by one as the heads are varying
    x1 -> a[ dir = none ];
    a -> x2[ dir = back ];
    x1 -> x3[ dir = none ];
    x2 -> x4[ dir = none ];
    b -> x4[ dir = none ];
    x3 -> b;
}
```

This gives you

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you - that works. I think I will use a first ones because I have a large graph, can not define each node with four empty nodes like a second ones.

Answer (score 1):

The head and tail position of an edge can be defined by using *compass points* as specified in [*The dot language*](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/lang.html), or by using the [`headport`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headport) or [`tailport`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:tailport) attributes:

```
digraph G{
  node [shape = "box"]
  a:w -> b:w
  b -> a [headport=e, tailport=e]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it works. I will use it.